# Is the Windows 10 Linux Subsystem useful in a dual-boot PC?

Tags: linux, windows, ubuntu, multi-boot, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I have just installed Ubuntu 17.10 alongside my Windows 10 installation. Windows 10 is my primary OS and I was wondering: is installing the Linux Subsystem for Windows 10 beneficial to the dual-boot setup, or not?

Comment: It depends on what you do with Linux. WSL only supports now CLI tools ( also with Xserver GUI). This question may be somehow opinion-based.

Comment: One of the things I would like to use is transferring files from Windows 10 to Linux.  I have in windows 10 some distros I packaged for Linux, and it would be great to just find and run them in the Windows 10 partition from Linux or transfer them from the windows 10 partition to the Linux partition and run them from there. I'm using Linux to test a Linux version of apps and games I'm developing for Windows 10 as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it would not be beneficial for the dual boot.

From [Microsoft's Windows Subsystem for Linux Documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/commandline/wsl/about)

> The Windows Subsystem for Linux lets developers run Linux environments -- including most command-line tools, utilities, and applications -- directly on Windows, unmodified, without the overhead of a virtual machine.

This would not affect or make benefit to the dual boot system you have as with the new feature, it only allows Windows to be able to run Linux applications and command-lines (etcetera).

As implicitly suggested by [this Reddit post](https://www.reddit.com/r/linuxmasterrace/comments/4imwmc/access_or_mount_an_ext4_partition_with_linux/) you won't even gain the ability to access other Linux extended subsystems (`ext?`) as you will still require drivers for accessing Linux filesystem files. So it won't do much in that respect. As you mentioned in your comment, you desire to gain access to the Linux filesystem architecture, the Reddit links provide that [Paragon ExtFS for Windows](https://www.paragon-software.com/home/extfs-windows/) would support that functionality.

Since it is already possible [to boot Grub from Windows Boot Manager](https://askubuntu.com/questions/62440/is-it-possible-to-boot-ubuntu-using-the-windows-bootloader) it does not particularly give in an advantage to the Windows Boot Manager, nor to Grub, in that respect.

However, it still remains useful for developers who want to run Linux software while using Windows architecture. So while it can be beneficial or useful to you, it does not directly support "the dual-boot setup" in any way, while as a setup to *you* it might be beneficial.